# Sql query to read the hardcoded values in oracle 11gR2

Tags: sql, oracle, boolean-logic

```
TABLE1
ID  DEPT_Inclusion(AND)          DEPT_Exclusion(OR)
E1  3 AND 4 AND 5 AND 6 AND 7    1 OR 2
E2  (1 OR 2) AND 3               4 OR 5
E3  1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4) AND 5   6 OR 7
E4  1 AND 3 AND 5                2 OR (3 AND 4)

TABLE2
ID  DEPT
E1  3
E1  4
E1  5
E1  6
E1  7
E2  1
E2  3
E2  4
E3  1
E3  2
E3  3
E3  4
E3  5
E4  1
E4  3
E4  5
E4  4


Expected Result:
ID
E1
E3
```

*Friends I need  help in building a query  to return the ID's that satisfy Dept_Inclusion criteria and it should not satisfy Dept_Exclusion criteria.
DEPT_Inclusion   and Dept_Exclusion values are hard coded.*

```
For example:
In the Table2
E1 satisfies the condition of Table1 inclusion and exclusion .(E1 is present in 3,4,5,6,7 and it is not present in 1 or 2)
E2 fails because it is present in Dept 4 which is a part of exclusion criteria.
E3 satisfies the condition
E4 fails because it is present in dept 3 AND 4.If it is present in only 3 and not 4 it would have satisfied the criteria.



 CODE

create table TABLE1 (id varchar2(5),Dept_Inclusion varchar2(100),Dept_Exclusion varchar2(100));

insert into TABLE1 VALUES('E1','3 AND 4 AND 5 AND 6 AND 7','1 OR 2');
insert into TABLE1 VALUES('E2','(1 OR 2) AND 3','4 OR 5');
insert into TABLE1 VALUES('E3','1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4) AND 5','6 OR 7');
insert into TABLE1 VALUES('E4','1 AND 3 AND 5','2 OR (3 AND 4)');

create table TABLE2 (id varchar2(5),Dept number);

insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E1',3);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E1',4);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E1',5);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E1',6);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E1',7);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E2',1);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E2',3);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E2',4);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E3',1);
'insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E3',2);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E3',4);
'insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E3',5);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E4',1);
'insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E4',3);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E4',5);
'insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E4',4);
```

Comment: Your data is highly denormalized. You almost have the pseudo code as the column values itself. Very poor design. Now you are into unnecessary trouble of extracting the part of the string to process the departments. Normalize your data first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to evaluate to evaluate the inclusion and exclusion criteria:

```
--This function evaluates the expression and return 1 for match, 0 or no match.
--Assumption: There are no nulls.
create or replace function is_match(p_inclusion varchar2, p_exclusion varchar2)
    return number
is
    v_sql varchar2(32767);
    v_count number;
begin
    --Create SQL statement that counts rows returns by expressions.
    --Convert pseudo-code into real code.
    --Each number gets changed into a query, `select id fro mtable2 where dept=EXPR`.
    --Then AND is changed to INTERSECT, OR is changed to UNION ALL.
    select
        replace(replace(regexp_replace(replace(replace(
        '
        select count(*)
        from
        (
            --Inclusions
            (
                %%INCLUSIONS%%
            )
            minus
            --Exceptions
            (
                %%EXCLUSIONS%%
            )
        )',
        '%%INCLUSIONS%%', p_inclusion),
        '%%EXCLUSIONS%%', p_exclusion),
        '([0-9]+)', 'select id from table2 where dept=\1'),
        'AND', 'intersect'),
        'OR', 'union all')
    into v_sql
    from dual;

    --Execute the query.
    execute immediate v_sql into v_count;

    --If it returns 1 or more row then there is a match.
    if v_count >= 1 then
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    end if;
end;
/
```

Then use that function in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select id
from table1
where is_match(dept_inclusion, dept_exclusion) = 1;

ID
--
E1
E3
```

I'm not sure why so many people voted to close this question as "not clear".  The question makes a lot of sense and you have provided better sample data than 99% of the questions on this site.  I somewhat agree that your data is "highly denormalized".  But normalizing expressions is not a trivial matter; it may make a lot of sense to keep the data the way it is.

Comment: If I am inserting the below rows                             'code'  insert into TABLE1 VALUES('E5','4 AND 5 AND 6 AND 7','1 OR 2');                    insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E5',4);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E5',5);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E5',6);
insert into TABLE2 VALUES('E5',7);  The function you provided is retuirning E5 also in out put.But it should not display E5 because it is not present in dept:3.I cant figure out why it is returning E5.Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Those inserts don't have anything related to dept:3?

Comment: No @Jon Heller.That is how the data is present.

Comment: I'm confused why that's an incorrect result.  `4 and 5 and 6 and 7` are inclusions, and the inserts are for 4, 5, 6, and 7.  `1 or 2` are the exclusions and none of the inserts add those departments to E5.

Comment: Sorry my bad.I gave wrong inserts.Thanks for your clarification.